# Rasa Nlu testing: TypeError: object pickle not returning list

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn, spacy, rasa-nlu

I'm trying to test rasa from Python and I'm getting an error, don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my metadata.json file

```
{
    "intent_classifier": "./model_20170206-173042/intent_classifier.pkl", 
    "entity_extractor": "./model_20170206-173042/ner", 
    "trained_at": "20170206-173042", 
    "training_data": "./model_20170206-173042/training_data.json", 
    "language_name": "en", 
    "feature_extractor": null, 
    "backend": "spacy_sklearn"
}
```

Here is my test.py file

```
from rasa_nlu.interpreters.spacy_sklearn_interpreter import SpacySklearnInterpreter
import json
metadata = json.loads(open('./model_20170206-173042/metadata.json').read())
interpreter = SpacySklearnInterpreter(**metadata)
interpreter.parse("How do I pay")
interpreter.parse("how can I pay")
```

And here is the Traceback of the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/proj/raasa/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    interpreter = SpacySklearnInterpreter(**metadata)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/rasa_nlu/interpreters/spacy_sklearn_interpreter.py", line 15, in __init__
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1217, in load_build
    setstate(state)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/ma/core.py", line 5518, in __setstate__
    ndarray.__setstate__(self, (shp, typ, isf, raw))

TypeError: object pickle not returning list
```

Is there anything wrong with the metadata file or is the interpreter wrong?

Comment: Which version of rasa NLU are you using?

Comment: @amirouche it was 0.4, I updated to 0.6, with MITIE it seems like it's an overlap problem, will try to solve that and let you know if the issue is still present

Comment: would be awesome to have a rasa-nlu tag

Comment: Not sure why but I am to strugling with `.pkl` files because of the Interpreter from `rasa_nlu.model`